# Passing user input to python script and displaying results

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, api

I'm still learning Python and even more so, how to interact between Python and HTML. I'm trying to pass user input to a python script located on the server that utilizes an API and then return results to the user on the webpage. So far this is where I'm stuck at (aka the beginning).

```
<input type="text" id="fileName" name="fileName" placeholder="File Name" required></input>
<button type"submit" value="Submit" onclick="runPython"></button>
```

Here I'm still need Java/JQuery to interact with the Python script located in /environments/threatcrowd.py. And below is the Python script to interact with the API to pull results from ThreatCrowd.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests, json
result = requests.get("http://www.threadcrowd.org/searchApi/v2/domain/report/", params = {"domain": "facebook.com"})
print(result.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Highly recommend you to use Flask or Django. it is very simple and useful. 
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/

Comment: this would be really useful if I was more proficient in Python. Like I said, I'm new and trying to learn.